# How to rotate tabs in linux terminal?

Tags: terminal, tabs, rotator

I would like to open several monitoring tools, each in one tab. I would like to automatically rotate tabs and display first tab1, wait 2 seconds, jump to tab2 wait, etc, something like tab rotator inside terminal. How to do this?

Comment: It depends on your terminal emulator.

Comment: i use gnome-terminal or xfce4-terminal.

Comment: This looks like a good place to start: https://askubuntu.com/questions/606383/how-to-set-active-tab-in-gnome-terminal